# how to display labels of empty profile fields

Tags: users

I have enabled profile2 module. There is profile type called personal information and it has related manage fields.I want to display the labels for empty profile fields on profile page. The fields are visible when it contains information but how to display the labels of empty profile fields to prompt the user to fill out empty fields. Does anyone have the solution? Please help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Empty Fields](http://drupal.org/project/empty_fields) module. With this you can place custom text as filler until content has been entered. This will have the labels show up.

Answer (score 1):

You should have searched on google ! visit this [page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1283974)